# vlcj media option "--no-overlay" doesn't work?

Tags: vlc, vlcj

I would like to turn off vlc's hardware acceleration option to avoid some lagging issue caused by a graphic card's driver bug. I tried to pass in that option in the prepareMedia method. That didn't help (as it would when I did it through command line: vlc --no-overlay 'path-to-video'). It actually even seemed to make the playback a bit more laggy. Below is part of my code to set up the player. I actually tried playMedia("path-to-video","--no-overlay") and that didn't work either.

```
mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
player = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer();
...
player.prepareMedia("path-to-video","--no-overlay");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those options must be passed when creating the `MediaPlayerFactory` rather than when playing the media - as to why it's like this, well it's just how LibVLC works.

If you're using `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` you can do something like this to supply those options:

```
mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent() {
    protected String[] onGetMediaPlayerFactoryArgs() {
        return new String[] {"--no-overlay"};
    }
}
```

Note that this will *replace* the default media player factory arguments so you might like to specify some other ones too - these are the defaults:

```
protected static final String[] DEFAULT_FACTORY_ARGUMENTS = {
    "--video-title=vlcj video output",
    "--no-snapshot-preview",
    "--quiet-synchro",
    "--sub-filter=logo:marq",
    "--intf=dummy"
};
```

So that is how you set such native VLC options, but whether this particular option will do what you actually want (and without any other side effects) is another matter.

Comment: Thank you so much! It does what I would like it to do - it does the same as if you pass in the --no-overlay option through command line :)